# Python 3 decimal module division still has floating point errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, decimal, precision

when using the decimal module in python, it seems that division still gives inaccurate results. Here is the code I used to check this, am I doing something wrong or is it just impossible to do division accurately with the decimal module? In that case, is there something else I could use to do this kind of calculations with accuracy?

```
from decimal import Decimal as D

a = D('39.37007874')
b = D('0.0254')
c = D('1')

print(c / a) #0.02540000000010160000000040640   unexpected
print(c / b) #39.37007874015748031496062992     unexpected
print(c * b) #0.0254                            expected
print(c * a) #39.37007874                       expected
```

Comment: Why do you think that output is not accurate? **This is accurate bro.**

Comment: @SharimIqbal Sorry, isn't it supposed to be 0.0254 and 39.37007874? I expected them to be. If they're not supposed to, is there any other way to get that answer?

Comment: Without decimal module is better. use `a = float('39.37007874')
b = float('0.0254')
c = float('1')` or directly `a = 39.37007874
b = 0.0254
c = 1`

Comment: >>> a*b
Decimal('0.999999999996')

Comment: @Sören Hmm.. So does that mean my input numbers are just not accurate enough to perform perfectly accurate calculations on them?

Comment: If you expect a*b to be 1, then yes, your numbers aren't accurate.

Comment: @Sören Alright, thanks for the information, this clarifies it. I didn't think that the input numbers would be incorrect. Thanks!

Comment: @GideonBear What is the source of those numbers?

Comment: @ekhumoro The source of those numbers is some random online conversion website, so I can understand those numbers are not 100% accurate. Now I am curious though, what is the actual perfect conversion ratio between meters and inches? Or is something like that impossible to get?

Comment: [… since the adoption of the international yard during the 1950s and 1960s the inch has been based on the metric system and defined as exactly 25.4 mm.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inch) Define `a` as the inverse of `b` and you are as good as it gets. Use `Fraction` instead of `Decimal` if you are worried about rounding precision.

Comment: @GideonBear Historically speaking, the inch has never had a universally agreed standard length. The most widely adopted standard now is to simply define the inch in metric terms as exactly 25.4mm.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve the accuracy by increasing the decimal context's precision, by either setting the global context (used in infix operations like `c / a`), or by using a `Context` instance to perform the operations:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal, Context, getcontext
>>> Decimal('1') / Decimal('0.0254')
Decimal('39.37007874015748031496062992')
>>> getcontext().prec
28
>>> getcontext().prec = 56
>>> Decimal('1') / Decimal('0.0254')
Decimal('39.370078740157480314960629921259842519685039370078740157')
>>> ctx = Context(prec=28)
>>> ctx.divide(Decimal('1'), Decimal('0.0254'))
Decimal('39.37007874015748031496062992')
>>> ctx = Context(prec=56)
>>> ctx.divide(Decimal('1'), Decimal('0.0254'))
Decimal('39.370078740157480314960629921259842519685039370078740157')
```

As others have pointed out though, `39.37007874 * 0.0254 != 1` so your expectation of what the results should be might be incorrect:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal, Context
>>> ctx = Context(prec=1000000)
>>> ctx.multiply(Decimal('0.0254'), Decimal('39.37007874'))
Decimal('0.999999999996')
```

Comment: None of this really helps, because (as stated in the comments to the question), the OP is actually trying to do metric/inch conversions. So even if the inch is defined as exactly 0.0254 metres, it isn't possible to calculate an equally exact number of inches in a metre. The figure of 39.37007874 inches is just an approximation, so it should not be used at all as the basis of calculations (assuming optimal accuracy is paramount).

Comment: I we forget about 39.37007874, and operate only with 0.0254, we can use the decimal precision to adjust the accuracy of the result as needed. This is particularly important given that `1 / 0.0254` results in a non terminating decimal, so we'd hit the precision limit for a lot of common decimal values when converting to inches.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I said. The two numbers don't have the same accuracy, so they shouldn't be used within the same calculation. Your answer only uses the number with the least accuracy, so changing the precision of the decimal context is misleading and wrong (i.e. precision != accuracy).

Comment: That's a fair point, I will update the answer to use 0.0254. I've never worked with the imperial system so neither of those two numbers is particularly familiar, I just took one of the two to illustrate the idea that the precision can be adjusted.

Comment: I see your edit, but it should be "improve the accuracy", rather than "precision". I also think it's worth pointing out that there's no neat way to define the number of inches in a metre. My old woodworking teacher used to say a metre was "three feet, three inches, three eighths", which equates to 39.375 inches. It's obviously possible to be more accurate than that, but there's no simple fraction that gives a truly exact conversion. So the answer to the OP's question is that they should base all their calculations on 25.4mm, and then round the final result to an appropriate precision.

Comment: Agree on "improve the accuracy". As for what the answer should be, we should let the OP edit the question to reflect what they really wanted to know, right now the question is still about the accuracy of operations using the `decimal` module, and the real question is in the comments.

Comment: Sorry to labour the point, but the OP specifically asks in their question whether they are "doing something wrong" and if "there something else I could use to do this kind of calculations with accuracy". The decimal module is largely irrelevant here, since the same issue will arise no matter which mathematical tool is employed. The fundamental point is that `1000 / 25.4` just doesn't resolve to an exact, simple fraction, so it's a poor choice as the basis for conversions.

Answer (score -1):

You could simply use the round function and get any number of decimals you need.

```py
from decimal import Decimal as D

a = D('39.37007874')
b = D('0.0254')
c = D('1')

print(round(c / a, 8)) #0.02540000
print(round(c / b, 8)) #39.37007874
print(round(c * b, 8)) #0.02540000
print(round(c * a, 8)) #39.37007874
```

Comment: Is there a way to receive this answer without using round? I am attempting to make my script as accurate as possible.

Comment: These two sentences contradict each other. 0.02540000000010160000000040640 IS MORE ACCURATE than 0.02540000, but for some reason you don't want that.

Comment: As beeing said this way you choose the accuratie is it 2, 6,10, 20 ... decimals. The most accurate is the one you have in your code. It all depends on what are you're going to do with the numbers later. Later you can always format them according to the logic of the script and your needs. Maybe you don't need to do anything with the results in the time of their very creation. They are good and accurate. If they are too accurate there is always round function or  some kind of format or conversion whatever suits you. Regards...

Comment: P. S.  Every of those numbers can have own number of decimals if you wish so....

Answer (score -1):

You may want to use `fractions`.

```
from fractions import Fraction

a = Fraction('39.37007874')
b = Fraction('0.0254')
c = Fraction(1)

print(c / a)  # 50000000/1968503937
print(c / b)  # 5000/127
print(c * b)  # 127/5000
print(c * a)  # 1968503937/50000000
```

This will make division as accurate as possible, although other operations like `sqrt()` or `sin()` will still be as accurate as `float`.

Comment: This does make it as accurate as possible, but still gives the same results when converted to a float. The problem was, my input numbers are not accurate.